# Toggleable accordion - slideUp other active accordion when clicking the current one

Tags: jquery

I'm currently making my own plugin (Self practice) Accordion.js

every accordion has the same class and I initialized them all via jquery :
my accordion toggles/slideToggle itself when clicking multiple times and I just want that whenever I clicked another accordion , it will slideUp the previous accordion you clicked and slideToggle the another one when you clicked it multiple times

heres my code anyway

```js
(function($) {
$.fn.accordion = function() {
var accordion = this;

accordion.find('.title').click(function() {
$(this).parent('.accordion').find('.content').slideToggle(200);
$(this).toggleClass('active');
});
return this;
};
  $('.accordion').accordion();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.accordion {
width:100%;
border:1px solid #ddd;
border-radius:6px;
margin:5px 0px;
}
.accordion > .title {
padding:10px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.accordion > .title + .content {
padding:0px 10px 10px 10px;
display:none;
}
.accordion > .title > .icon {
position:relative;
right:-84%;
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
color:#666;
transition:all 200ms linear;
}
.accordion > .title.active > .icon {
-webkit-transform:none;
color:#666;
transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
<div class="title">Open 
<i class="dropdown icon"></i> </div>
<div class="content"> 
<h1> Accordion 1</h1> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
<div class="title">Open 
<i class="dropdown icon"></i> </div>
<div class="content"> 
<h1> Accordion 2</h1> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
<div class="title">Open 
<i class="dropdown icon"></i> </div>
<div class="content"> 
<h1> Accordion 3</h1> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
<div class="title">Open 
<i class="dropdown icon"></i> </div>
<div class="content">
<h1> Accordion 4</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need. The approach here is that i have added the active class to the content div also and after that removing it when toggling a pane. And slideUp all the panes not having the active class except the one on which the user clicks i.e the one having the active class. Hope it helps.

```js
$.fn.accordion = function() {
var accordion = this;
accordion.find('.title').click(function() {
$(document).find('.title').removeClass('active');
$(document).find('.content').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent('.accordion').find('.content').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
$('.content:not(".active")').slideUp(200);
});
return this;
};

$('.accordion').accordion();
```

```css
.accordion {
width:100%;
border:1px solid #ddd;
border-radius:6px;
margin:5px 0px;
}
.accordion > .title {
padding:10px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.accordion > .title + .content {
padding:0px 10px 10px 10px;
display:none;
}
.accordion > .title > .icon {
position:relative;
right:-84%;
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
color:#666;
transition:all 200ms linear;
}
.accordion > .title.active > .icon {
-webkit-transform:none;
color:#666;
transition: all 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
<div class="title">Open 
<i class="dropdown icon"></i> </div>
<div class="content"> 
<h1> Accordion 1</h1> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
<div class="title">Open 
<i class="dropdown icon"></i> </div>
<div class="content"> 
<h1> Accordion 2</h1> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
<div class="title">Open 
<i class="dropdown icon"></i> </div>
<div class="content"> 
<h1> Accordion 3</h1> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
<div class="title">Open 
<i class="dropdown icon"></i> </div>
<div class="content">
<h1> Accordion 4</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hL90g1m4/)**

Comment: Finally someone made it perfectly , Thanks alot to you bro :)

Comment: @Jeffson you are welcome. Always Happy to help :)  if this helped you mark it as a answer.

Comment: there it is bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution

```
//inside your function body after var accordion = this;
var trigger = accordion.find('.title');

trigger.on("click",function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active').next('.content').slideUp(200);
    } else {
        accordion.find('.content').slideUp(200);
        trigger.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active').next('.content').slideDown(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: What you mean by that? If you dont want continuous close/ collapse beahaviour when clicking the same accordion title, then wrap everything inside click function in additional if construction: if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) { -- do code }. Otherwise i suggest to consider describing your case more precisely

Comment: I just want an accordion that slideToggle itself when clicking and close itself when clicking another , anyway the class 'active' affects only the child of '.title' class , not the accordion itself

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `each` function [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3r3zt29j/#&togetherjs=A2Q31QDv7P):

JS:

```
$.fn.accordion = function() {
var accordion = this;

accordion.find('.title').click(function() {

$(document).find('div.accordion').each(function(){
$(this).find('.content').slideUp(200);
});
$(this).parent('.accordion').find('.content').slideToggle(200);
$(this).toggleClass('active');
});
return this;
};

$('.accordion').accordion();
```

Comment: if you click on the same pane it will not close/ collapse.

Comment: I think this may helps! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h621g3x8/#&togetherjs=iKN6xSwiAo)

Comment: vispan : almost close to what I've expected , however , it doesn't slideToggle itself when click multiple times